# Setting primary email and phone upon contact update

Tags: import, primary

We want to update a bunch of contacts with e-mail adresses and phone numbers, for which previously these did not exist. The import works fine, as a result the contacts now have a Home (for example) e-mail and phone, but these are not set as the Primary ones. Because of this, the new e-mails and phone numbers do not show up in reports, and cannot be used in contact search. Only when I view one of the updated contacts, click into the Email field and then, without changing anything, press Save, the email is set to Primary.

It appears that when the contact is first created, in case there is no e-mail or phone, the Primary flag is not set. During contact update, the address/phone is updated, but the Primary flag is left missing. Is it possible to set the e-mail and phone to Primary during import if these did not exist previously?

We're currently using CiviCRM 4.7.14.

Comment: What CMS are you using?

Comment: Could you please edit your question to let us know the version of CiviCRM you're running? Does the problem happen when you try to replicate it at http://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/?

Comment: Yes, I can verify that the issue can be replicated on the demo site.

Comment: Connected JIRA issue: https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-21081

Answer (score 3):

That sounds like a bug - can you confirm you ran the import via the CiviCRM GUI?

On fixing this for you - do you have access (or work with someone) who has - to phpMyAdmin or MySQL?

Comment: Yes, I was using the CiviCRM GUI (4.7.14). I personally do not have access to phpMyAdmin or MySQL, but somebody else almost definitely has.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the this same issue for at least a couple years now. I created this extension to "fix" the issue. It looks for related records (phone,email,address) of a contact and when none, or more than one are set to primary it sets just one to primary. Uses the sites default location type for primary.

https://github.com/proexchange/com.pesc.primaryfix

Comment: Hi Jose - have you seen https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/org.wikimedia.datachecks?  It seems like it covers some similar ground.  Thoughts?